# jQuery Newbie, need some assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

[Please check the HTML code](http://notes.io/aPEJ) now. Entering the script file code, I don't know what these lines do:

```
$workEntryForm = $("[rel*=js-work-entry-form");
$workEntrySelectProject = $workEntryForm.find("[rel*=js-select-project]");
var $workEntryForm, $workEntrySelectProject;
```

can anyone explain, what is assigned to the `$workEntryForm`?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is **[attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

`$("[rel*=js-work-entry-form")` selects all the elements which contains the `rel` attribute with `js-work-entry-form` string as part of the value.

```
<div id="one" rel="prefix-js-work-entry-form"></div>
<div id="two" rel="js-work-entry-form-suffix"></div>
<div id="three" rel="prefix-js-work-entry-form-suffix"></div>
<div id="four" rel="prefix"></div>
```

In the above `HTML` it selects `divs` with id's `one`, `two` and `three` as these elements have the rel attribute which is part of the selection.

Comment: You should probably also warn about it not being a valid selector from 2.2.0. See first post on [this issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/issues/140). Correct syntax is `$("rel*='js-work-entry-form'")`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu True, it is always a better practice to encase the value inside quotes

Comment: It actually only affects attributes containing hashes, but since that incident, I always quote correctly. I don't know when they will change it to not supporting at all. Better safe than sorry. I suppose it's all down to the CSS spec for selectors. And that's pretty clear: quote.